# Extract text (2 char) at specific no of characters after a specific pattern in a text file

Tags: search, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file full of 'transfer frames' (each line) and I want to extract the 'sequence counter' which is 2 characters (1 byte) exactly 48 characters after the '**8100**' marker, e.g. the first one in bold below is '1b'.
I would like to output each of these 'counters' into a text file, each on a separate line, to be able to identfy where they are 'out of sequence'. Can this be done easily with **awk **or **sed**?
thanks for any help!

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**8100**000000000000000000000000000000010101443e000049b7**1b**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 ...
Line   30: /1acffc1d003192b9180008b4f72e00831003190051d6ba1e0c77351f000000070002ca81000000010000

Do not have the expertise with either awk or sed to be able to attempt this.

Comment: Yes it can be done easily with awk but this forum exists to help people with their code, not to write code for people for free, so read some awk documentation and try it for yourself then come back here with code if you run into problems.

Comment: There are 4 instances of `8100` in your sample, so you need to define "marker" more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might work:

```
grep -Po '(?<=8100.{48})..' file
```

Using perl regex and a lookbehind of 8100 followed by 48 chars, output only the two chars after that.

This outputs this for your input:

```
00
01
1b
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/8100.{48}(..)/   \n\1\n/g;/^..\n/P;D' file
```

Remove the original match and insert newlines either side of the result.

The results are only two characters long and can be selectively printed using the `/regex/P` and `D` idiom.